# $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my `<head>` of the .php when i imported the scripts and css.

```
<!--JQUERY-->
<script       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<!--JQUERY-UI-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- BS JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--CSS BOOTSTRAP-->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- SIDEBAR CSS -->
<link href="../css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Modal Form-->
<?php include "modal_form_detalle_parteMantenimiento.php"; ?>
```

This is the function that open the modal form with the information

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                           var id_clickat=0;
                           $('[name=detalles]').click(function(){
                               id_clickat = $(this).val();

                                $.post( "../php/ajaxParteMantenimiento.php",{id_c : id_clickat, mostrar : true}, function( data )                           
                        {    
                            $("#contenidoDetalleMant").html(data);
                            $('#contenidoDetalleMant').modal('show');
                        });
                           });
                       });
```

The modal form is simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="pintarAsiTot">
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

</head>

<body>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="detalleParteMantenimiento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" 
               data-dismiss="modal">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                Detalle Parte Mantenimiento
            </h4>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
              <div class="form-group" id="contenidoDetalleMant">                            




                </div>



              </div>
              <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
            </div>

            </form>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>


</div>
```

The problem is that when I click on the button does not open the form. ¿WHAT?

Comment: $("[name=detalles]") work correctly, but the ajax petition is realized.

Comment: Can you comment out jquery-ui and run it see if it fixes if not try to see jquery is not loaded twice.

Comment: Jquery-Ui is comented and don`t open modal.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: In this moment is impossible, sorry.

Comment: try this $("#detalleParteMantenimiento").modal('show')

Comment: $(...).modal is not a function, not working.

Comment: are you using customized bootstrap.js ???

Comment: The id of modal is "detalleParteMantenimiento", but the sentence $("#detalleParteMantenimiento").modal('show') returns " 
$(...).modal is not a function"

Comment: are you getting data correctly with ajax ??

Comment: Yes, i get all the information.

Comment: Is your path to the bootstrap js file definitely correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the modal ID is *detalleParteMantenimiento* and not *contenidoDetalleMant*, try changing that.

If that doesn't work, I would check if Jquery is loaded correctly or if it's loaded twice, maybe it's included in your layout page.

**Workaround**

What you can do is add a hidden button like this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnToOpenModal" style="display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detalleParteMantenimiento"> </button>
```

And then call a click on this button in your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                       var id_clickat=0;
                       $('[name=detalles]').click(function(){
                           id_clickat = $(this).val();

                            $.post( "../php/ajaxParteMantenimiento.php",{id_c : id_clickat, mostrar : true}, function( data )                           
                    {    
                        $("#contenidoDetalleMant").html(data);
                        $("#btnToOpenModal").click();
                    });
                       });
                   });
```